# Pushing stored procedure to a multisite database in WordPress

Tags: multisite, customization, mysql, recursive

I am given a WordPress multisite and need to extract information from the site.
I have written a stored procedure that recursively builds a tree relationship for posts of a certain kind.
Now I am wondering how to push the stored procedure to the databases of all the sites.(Since this is a multisite configuration, each site(subdomain in this case) has a separate database.)

Please help me in this regard.

WordPress version: 3.5.1
Multisite config type: subdomains

```
//code needs refinement

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getPath(IN post_id INT, IN return_path TEXT)

BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE a INT;
 DECLARE b TEXT;
 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR (SELECT * FROM TempTable112);     
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable112;

 SET max_sp_recursion_depth := 10;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable112 AS SELECT id,post_title FROM wp_101_posts WHERE post_parent = post_id and post_status='publish'; 

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ',"'", CONCAT('Sample',FLOOR(1000+RAND()*9999)),'.txt',"'",' FROM TempTable112');
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a,b;
    IF done = 1 THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
         SET return_path = CONCAT('/',return_path,b);
     CALL getPath(a, return_path);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please show us your code (and add **much more** info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Steps:

STEP 01 : Put code in a Text File

Open up a text editor (vi, nano, emacs) and place your code in it.

Save it as `/tmp/mynewcode.sql`

STEP 02 : Collect All Databases Names

```
MYSQLCONN=`-uroot -ppassword`
SQLSTMT="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT IN"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')"
mysql ${MYSQLCONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/dbnames.txt
```

STEP 03 :  Load Stored Procedure into every database mentioned in `/tmp/dbnames.txt`

```
for DB in `cat /tmp/dbnames.txt` ; do mysql ${MYSQLCONN} -D${DB} < /tmp/mynewcode.sql ; done
```

STEP 04 : Remove the files you made (OPTIONAL)

```
rm -f /tmp/dbnames.txt
rm -f /tmp/mynewcode.sql
```

That's it.

Give it a Try !!!